# Pass parameters with nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have this file https://www.example.com/directory/file1.js?sv=d&ss=tglp&v=11

I would need to create an nginx url rewrite to a non existing file file2.js and pass all parameters sv= / ss= / v=

I tried this code:

```
location = /file2.js {
rewrite ^ /directory/file1.js last;
}
```

It works but doesn't pass the parameters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

URL params are always passed with `rewrite`:

```
server {
  rewrite ^(/directory)/file2\.js$ $1/file1.js break;
  ...
}
```